# Domainfactory + heroku name server

Tags: heroku, dns

I own a domain on the German provider domainfactory and would like to set an A record to my heroku app to connect domain + app. I've never done this before so was looking up different blogs and hints how to do it. At the moment I just have a simple redirect which is obviously quite ugly as my domain gets lost completely.

I followed this dude's introduction here:
http://d.hatena.ne.jp/akipponn3/20120626/1340706654

After changing the A record and connected my domain via

```
heroku domains:add www.example.com
```

it pointed to an "app not found" page on heroku after some hours.

I was texting with the domainfactory support and they told me to look up the correct nameserver IP addresses on heroku but I googled the hell out of this and could not find any.

My next step would be to try this via amazon route53 but first would like to check any best practices if I can reach my goal somehow very easily.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made everything running via https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/route-53
The nameserver can easily be entered in the domainfactory category "Für Profis".

Comment: Hello Martin, I have the same problem. How did you actually do it? Which DNS records did you enter? Did you do as the Article told you (make root.com redirect to www.root.com)? How does that work on df.eu?  Since df auto redirects www to the apex domain I couldn't figure out how to set an appropriate CNAME / ARecord for root.

Comment: i'm having the same issue here. especially ssl seems to be a problem. can you elaborate a little?

Comment: @cessor i blogged about how to use it here: http://nofail.de/2014/07/using-domainfactory-with-heroku-and-ssl/

Answer (score 1):

Since I just stumbled upon this again (accounts for domain factory and heroku or evennode alike services with fixed domain, dynamic ip):

1. take all a and cname records out
2. put one a record to point to domainfactory
3. put one cname record to point to heroku with wildcard domain *.example.com
4. go to the domain settings of example.com and put as forward http(s)://www.example.com

check :) -> at least if you are fine with having www... as standard subdomain

Answer (score 0):

CloudFlare is not free and costs about 20$ / month.
I have another solution which will work better and have no costs.
Just go to "Nameserver-Einstellungen" under Menu "Für Profis".

Here we add a CNAME entry. Because you can not use the root domain, we use * which will redirect all subdomains.

Now we go in the domain settings, editing the domain itself.
We route the domain into our webspace folder, where we have an .htaccess 
Put this in your .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.railszilla.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This will redirect the call from the root domain to the WWW address. This is more SEO friendly and it do not has any costs.

Best regards